# Load a different fragment into android app when clicking on a fixed tab

Tags: java, android, eclipse

At the moment im new to Android OS and trying to get my head around fragments - creating an app from iOS into Android so i need to try figure this out!

I have used the fixed tab default setting in Eclipse IDE, which gives me 3 tabs. I can change the tab menu names however I am trying to load in a different fragment lets say: `fragment_1`, `fragment_2` and `fragment_3` when the title is clicked.

I have found this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
    return rootView;
}
```

and I have changed the layout to `fragment_1`, but how can I load fragment_x where x is the tab clicked? Is this possible? I have searched the net, but nothing has worked or made sense so far!

Comment: Simply check for fragmenttabhost I guess u looking for some functionality like tabs it might be what i guess u might be looking for with using fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created your project through Eclipse, in your main activity you should see a private class named `DummySectionFragment`. Use that class as a guide to create three classes which will be your three different fragments (A,B & C).

There should also be a class named `SectionsPagerAdapter` with the following method

> public Fragment getItem(int position){}

Now change the contents of the `getItem` method to something like

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0){
       return new MyFragmentA();
    }else if (position == 1){
       return new MyFragmentB();
    }else { // position == 2
       return new MyFragmentC();
    }
}
```

Where `MyFragmentA/B/C` are the fragements you created in the first step.
Also take a look at [Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) before experimenting further.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, You should create 3 different fragments and 3 different layouts for each of them. Then in your Host activity, you should display the appropriate fragment on the respective tab button click.

See [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) to learn how to make fragments part of a host activity and make them visible and invisible.

However, this is not the recommended way to use tabs in Android. Directly porting iOS style tabs to Android will lead to an inferior user experience. Tabs are meant to be either part of the [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) or you can implement tabbed swipe views using a [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

See [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html) for more.